# Javascript load correct page using router when user enters URL manually

Tags: javascript, html

I was busy trying to create a router in Javascript when I stumpled upon a problem.

I created this router that works for the most part (not optimal, but still W.I.P):

```
class Router {
    constructor() {
        // Declare root
        this.root = document.querySelector("#root");

        // Declare routes
        this.routes = {
            "/": home,
            "/about": about,
        };

        this.currentPath = window.location.pathname;
        this.root.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", this.routes[this.currentPath]);

        // USED FOR TESTING THE ROUTE
        document.querySelector("#clickableButton").addEventListener("click", () => {
            this.currentPath = window.location.pathname + "about"
        })

        this.listenForChanges();
    }

    listenForChanges = () => {
        // listen for changes
        setInterval(() => {
            if (this.currentPath != window.location.pathname)
            {
                history.pushState(null, null, this.currentPath);

                // Insert page into root of HTML
                this.root.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", this.routes[this.currentPath]);
            }
        }, 50);
    }
}

new Router();
```

With the corresponding HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>

    <script src="home.js"></script>
    <script src="about.js"></script>
    <script src="router.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">
    <button id="clickableButton">CLICK ME</button>
    <div id="root">

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

for clarity:

home.js:

```
const home = `
    <h1>HOME PAGE!</h1>
`
```

about.js:

```
const about = `
    <h1>ABOUT PAGE!</h1>
`
```

My router works for the most part, it changes the URL (without reloading) and appends the correct page data. But if my URL has changed for example to "/about" and then if I refresh the page, it gives an error that the "object can not be found", of course because it is an invalid URL.

How can I make it that when a user types in the URL manually, it goes through my router and loads the correct page?

Comment: Your server needs to rewrite all path URLs to your main index file. With apache for instance you'd use `mod_rewrite` commands in `.htaccess`.

Comment: @ChrisG Oh, so you mean that it always redirects to the home ("/") path of the application?

Comment: Yes. If you're using node/express for instance, you'd simply deliver the index file on your `/` route, catching all URLs that don't map to a static file. Which server *are* you using?